# How to refresh only pie chart on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```
<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},10000);

function myTimer() {
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "hello";
}
</script>
<div id="show">
        <canvas id="chart-area2" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>
```

The above displays piechart for 10 seconds and then replaces the piechart with  'hello'. In the place of 'hello' how can i make the piechart display again? Will this code refresh the div every 10 seconds? if not then what are the changes i have to do?

the div tag displays the pie chart on the browser.

Comment: Instead of setting innerHTML to 'hello' you should call the method that's rendering the chart.

Comment: window.onload = function(){
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
    var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);
    
   };                                                        how to add this to inner html

Comment: @user3799981 Above code will trigger every 10 sec. When exactly do you want to refresh the data..? dumping code blocks in comments is highly discouraged. Please edit the question and update more specific info to get a proper answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},10000);

    function myTimer() {
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d"); 
        var pieData2 = ... //You can use AJAX to load new data from the server if you want
        var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);
    }
</script>
<div id="show">
    <canvas id="chart-area2" width="300" height="300"/>
</div>
```

Comment: pieData2= [
    {
     value: <?= $pfstatetext;?>,
     color:"#F7464A",
     highlight: "#FF5A5E",
     label: "Red :"
    },
    {
     value: <?= $cpuusage; ?>,
     color: "#46BFBD",
     highlight: "#5AD3D1",
     label: "Green"
    },
    {
     value: 100,
     color: "#FDB45C",
     highlight: "#FFC870",
     label: "Yellow"
    },
    {
     value: 40,
     color: "#949FB1",
     highlight: "#A8B3C5",
     label: "Grey"
    },
    {
     value: 120,
     color: "#4D5360",
     highlight: "#616774",
     label: "Dark Grey"
    }

   ];
How to update this data in the script?

Comment: You should only define the line I wrote...you can write what you want, like what you've written. But if you want to update the data from the server, use AJAX.